# Print \n as actual newline in terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In my RSpec email tests I render some text views with newlines:

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def email1
    @foo = "Hello"
    @bar = "World"
    mail(to: "test@example.com", subject: "Foobar")
  end
end
```

This is the view `email1.text.erb`

```
<%= @foo %>

<%= @bar %>
```

And this is my test:

```
it 'renders output' do
  body = MyMailer.email1.body
  puts body
end
```

When I print the email body in terminal, ruby returns `\n` instead of an actual newline:

```
Hello\n\nWorld
```

> For debugging purpose it would be nice to have the actual newlines instead of `\n` printed in my terminal. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Well, this is sort of weird. What do you get with `body.encoding`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is something off with your encoding. Since this is only for debug purpose, you can fix it with:

```
puts body.to_s.gsub('\n', "\n")
```

(Note the difference between quotes!). To fix it the correct way, you need to tell what is your body encoding as it is being used for transforming your raw message body to ruby string.

Comment: `\n` is platform-specific. Consider using `$/` instead.

Comment: @mudasobwa- There is some issue with mail encoding, mail gem should automatically detect line ends. I cannot tell what went wrong during the conversion of raw email body to ruby string and definitively cannot tell what platform is the code running - it can be windows so changing `'\n'` might actually prevent it from working. Since this is for debug only, it is `good enough`, however the encoding should be investigated further.

Comment: I doubt changing anything in call to `puts` might break something. In fact, using `$/` instead of `\n` would make this code working fine on Windows machine _as well_.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to do this in `email1.text.erb`

```
<%= @foo + '\n' + @bar %>
```

Comment: Did you try with '\n' qoute?

Answer (score -1):

you must escape characters. use `\\n`

Comment: When I do a `puts body.gsub("\n", "\\n")` it just returns `"Hello\\n\\nWorld"` but no new lines in terminal.